# Select all rows except first one for each different value of specific column

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I stuck with some SQL query. Let's say I have DB table like:

```
user_hash | created_on
xxx         1
xxx         10
xxx         100
yyy         2
yyy         20
yyy         200
```

I need to select all rows except the one with the lowest `created_on` value for each `user_hash` so I want my results to be like:

```
user_hash | created_on
xxx         10
xxx         100
yyy         20
yyy         200
```

I know how to select it for specific `user_hash` using offset:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE user_hash = ‘xxx’
ORDER BY created_on ASC
OFFSET 1 ROW;
```

but I can't figure it out how to do this for all `user_hash` in one query. I was trying with grouping, subqueries and joins but with no effect. Could someone help me with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can try using `ROW_NUMBER` here, assuming it is available in your database:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_hash ORDER BY created_on) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT user_hash, created_on
FROM cte
WHERE rn > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.created_on > (select min(t2.created_on)
                      from t t2
                      where t2.user_hash = t.user_hash
                     );
```